# How to solve 16 coupled linear equation?

Tags: equation-solving

How one can solve 16 or more linear simultaneous equation in mathematica?
If there are 16 coupled linear equations with 16 variables, then how it is to be solved in mathematica?

Comment: Since ther equations are linear, they can be placed in matrix form. Then solve for the unknowns using LinearSolve.

Comment: You can use `CoefficientArrays[]` if you want to convert a bunch of linear expressions into a matrix of coefficients.

Comment: An answer can be only as detailed as the question. If my answer is satisfactory, great. If not: next time please try to post the question in a manner that it won't require several rounds of clarifications. StackExchange does not aim to be a discussion forum. The idea is to ask clear, focused questions, and get direct answer.  Please take the tour: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: One possibility is to do something like this :  `Solve[{x+y==1,x-3y==7},{x,y}]`

Answer (score 3):

Write it as a matrix equation and use [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html).

Answer (score 3):

The following illustrates a simple way to solve a set of linear equations.  It works for larger values of `m`, e.g. `m=16` but for illustration, just use a small value

```
m = 3;
```

Define some random equations.  We don't need to have integer coefficients, but it makes a nice illustration.  Note that we don't need to think of names for all 16 variables, we can just use `x[1]` etc.

```
randeq[n_] := 
 Sum[RandomInteger[10] x[j], {j, 1, n}] == RandomInteger[10]
```

Now generate a list of the random equations

```
equations = Table[randeq[m], {m}]
(* {3 x[1] + 8 x[2] == 4, 2 x[1] + 4 x[2] + 4 x[3] == 9, 
 4 x[1] + 8 x[2] + x[3] == 10} *)
```

Solve them

```
solution = Solve[equations, Array[x, m]]
(* {{x[1] -> 34/7, x[2] -> -(37/28), x[3] -> 8/7}} *)
```

and verify the solution

```
equations /. solution
(* {{True, True, True}} *)
```